# What method can be used to test if three or more categorical sample data sets are from the same distribution?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, categorical-data

I have three data sets like this:

data1: {A, A, B, C, D, ..}
data2: {A, B, B, C, E, ...}
data3: {A, C, D, D, E, ...}

How do I test if these three data sets are from the same distribution?

Answer (score 2):

After looking around, I think chi-square test of independence is the best one for such data.

Comment: The method is chi-square test of **independence**, not that of **goodness of fit**, as I have no idea what $D$ I should test for. Ordering the categories doesn't quite work either. There are 67 categories in my data, trying each ordering for these categories is computationally unfeasible. However, thanks for the effort for answering (the diagrams are awesome!)